# Call node.js method from Java code

Tags: java, node.js

I know that sounds a little weird.

But I need to call a node.js method from a Java code.

Is it possible? If so, how can I do that?

I already tried to solve my problem with nashorn but it doesn't run jquery, and I can't do what I need with simple javascript.

Comment: Could you share some of what you need to do with node.js? Perhaps the problem can be solved in a way you haven't thought of.

Comment: I need to check the size of an element inside a html file. I can't do that font end side because it's an API. Check this info in the "hard" way is hard :P because I can have the height/width defined by inline css, external css, js... So, I could do this with pure JS, but I only have the complete HTML, so, I can only create an element "iframe" and set the "innerHTML", and doing that, I couldn't get the element I need because JS not return the elements inside the iframe, I don't know why

Comment: JAVA and javascript are not the same. While there are ways to make interoperability of languages work, you're probably going about this the wrong way. What is your actual problem?

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll Hi, I know they aren't the same, that's why I need to use both... I need front end info inside my backend code...

Comment: @clesiemo3 Any idea?

Comment: @Gabrielle `NodeJS` is used for server side implementation and it is written in javascript. As all popular browsers support javascript and HTML/HTML5 uses lot of javascript API - hence there is great benefit for the re-usability of code for both serverside as well as clientside(front end). If you want to do with `Java` with `javascript`  for the frontend work, you can use frontend `javascript` framework. There are several and one of the popular one is `Angularjs`. You can check it from  https://angularjs.org/

Comment: @Altius My problem cannot be resolved with both languages separately, I have an API made in Java and I don't have time to re-write it in Node.I need to check an element size inside an html file.I can't do this in Java unless I check CSS inline/infile/external, JS inline/infile/external, so it's not an option, and I don't have an interface to check this in the client side. So, I know that JS is for frontend and Java for backend, but, how can I check the size if I only have a file with all html code inside?Yeah, I could re-write all the API, but there is a lot functions not only this size check.

Comment: @Gabrielle I didn't get. Why you want to check CSS all those stuff with Java. Show the problem with some examples that we can help.

Comment: @Altius I have an API that receives an html file and then shows it into another system, like if you could send your post or comment in html file, and I just put your code in my site, the problem is that every user has a dimension limit and I can't let the user upload his code, if I know that he is using more space than the permitted. I just want to check it.

Comment: I get it, using Runtime.exec and passing the command as in command line.